# How can I remove the lines being output in my 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays

When I run the program, I get lines in between the elements of my 2d array.

[image] How do I get rid of them? I meant to have empty values

```
cout << "  ";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << i << " ";
cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i << " ";
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        cout << grid[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is `grid`? Have you initialized it?

Comment: Yes I did char grid[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS]; in my main function. [10] [10]  they are const int

Comment: I added the + but now the values are initialized to -52

Comment: I'll believe it when I see it. Next time, please try to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `char grid[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];` is not an initialization, it just creates the grid with garbage inside it. If you want to have empty spaces you have to do something like:

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < MAX_COLS; j++) {
        grid[i][j] = ' ';
    }
}
```